# css file status 403

Tags: css, import

I am importing some css files in another css document like so, however the foundation.css file is getting a 403 for the stylesheet when I visit the location, my ftp says it is there and it all works locally. The site is live [here](http://www.austin.kitson.org/update/wordpress-1/tech-basics/) username:anders pass:reading61 I am not sure what is going on.

```
/*
Theme Name: git.Austin.Kitson.org
Theme URI: http://austin.kitson.org
Description: A Wordpress version of Austin.kitson.org
Author: springmethod
Author URI: http://springmethod.com
Version: 1.0
*/
/*import styles for zurbs foundation*/
@import url("stylesheets/foundation.css");
@import url("stylesheets/app.css");
[if lt IE 9] @import url("stylesheets/ie.css");
```

here is my functions.php css register and enqueue if that helps

```
//LOAD CSS
function load_css_styles(){
if (!is_admin()){
wp_register_style('css_main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style('css_main');
}// if not admin ends
}// css_styles ends
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css_styles');
```

Comment: 403 is a permissions error, check that the file has proper permissions for public access on your server

Comment: @Milo wow your the best milo, what is a proper permissions number. I set my wp-content to 777 to test and it all works, but I dont think that is a secure permission I dont know though, previously it was all set to 755, shouldn't that work?

Comment: @Milo ok well i changed back to 755 and set it recursively, I guess just foundation.css had a different permission, working great now, could you possible answer the question so I could choose it as the answer.

Comment: Files should be 444 or 644 and directories 755.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[403 Forbidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) is a permissions error, check that the file has proper permissions for public access on your server.